# Convert URI to File URI (file:////)

Tags: firefox-addon, file-uri

In my addon I'm allowing people to browse to an image on their disk. When they do this the file path returned (using the inline options file control) is in form of `C:\blah\blah\blah.png`. I then take this file path and set a stylesheet using this path:
`list-style-image: url("' + newValRep + '")`

However how can I convert this in a proper way to to `file:////C:/blah/blah/blah.png` because if i use the first way it doesnt work in my css style sheet.

Currently I'm doing this regex:
`var newValRep = 'file:///' + newuri.replace(/\\/g, '/');`

but this is definitely not the proper way as it is windows specific.

I have tried:

- `new FileUtils.File(newuri).path` but this does not give `file:///` form
- `OS.Path.normalize(newuri)` but same problem
- `Services.io.newURI(newuri, null, null).spec` but same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close :-)

```js
var uri = Services.io.newFileURI(somensILocalFile)
console.log(uri.spec)
```

Comment: Ah thanks man! I was exploring `[nsIProtocolHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProtocolHandler)` is it possible to do it with this one too? That way I can skip making it a nsIFile, so right now I'm doing `var uri = Services.io.newFileURI(new FileUtils.File(pathToMyFile).spec`

Comment: @Noitidart apparently `OS.Path.toFileURI` does exactly what you want, without any sanity checks.

Comment: Oh wow!! Super thanks man!!! I couldn't find this in the docs, should I add it? How did you find this? So arguments are it just takes a a normalized string?

Comment: It takes the file path as a string and returns the url also as a string.

Comment: Also to set something straight, `OS.Path.toFileURI` merely takes a string, applies some conversion to it and returns the result. That means `OS.Path.toFileURI("Ω:❤\\Σίγμα")` will happily return `file:///Ω:/❤/Σίγμα`

Comment: Ah thanks for that calrification. How does the `newFileURI` method differ other than taking string. Doesn't it jus take the string of the `spec` from the `nsIFile`?

Comment: I don't know if, and how, `newFileURI` and `toFileURI` differ. But the former implies a call to `initWithPath` which does some rudimentary checks (e.g. a valid drive letter on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

For the reference for others.

Thanks to @paa I've been using `OS.Path.toFileURI`. However I needed the basename of the uir, and doing `OS.Path.basename` on a file uri does not return as expected. Example on this file uri: `file:///C:/Users/Vayeate/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/android_normal.png` it would return basename of: `/Users/Vayeate/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/android_normal.png`

I want the `android_normal.png`. So i had to do reverse of `toFileURI` and OS.File ships with that as seen here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/components/osfile/modules/ospath_unix.jsm#162

There is a function called `OS.Path.fromFileURI`

Doing `OS.Path.basename(OS.Path.fromFileURI(path))` succesfully returns `android_normal.png`.