# Convert media uri to document uri

Tags: android, kotlin

My file picker returns the uri as `content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000192721`

but i need it as

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A1000192721
```

How to do that ? Update : it returns a null value

What i tried is

```
fun getDocumentUriFromMediaUri(context: Context, mediaUri: Uri): Uri? {
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
    val selection = "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA} = ?"
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(mediaUri.path)

    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null
    )

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
        val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
        cursor.close()
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)
    }

    return null
}
```

References

[android : file Uri to Content Uri. (converting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668639/android-file-uri-to-content-uri-converting)

[Convert URI to File URI (file:////)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879160/convert-uri-to-file-uri-file)

[android : file Uri to Content Uri. (converting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668639/android-file-uri-to-content-uri-converting)

Comment: so you write, you have tried, what is the issue with what you have tried?

Comment: it returns a null value

Comment: MediaStore has a static function that does what you want.

Comment: `but i need it as` But that is also a media uri. And what is a document uri?

Comment: You could explain why your media uri does not suit you.

Comment: `getDocumentUriFromMediaUri()` There is nothing in that function with document uries. Whatever you think they are.

Comment: MediaStore has a static function that converts a media(store) uri to a document file uri. But you have not a media uri

Comment: Could you please share the use case? What will you use this Uri for? I may have a suggestion if you need the Uri only for a short period of time

Comment: https://github.com/a914-gowtham/android-video-trimmer preview not available in the first uri thats why i need in second format